# Why won't my function execute?

Tags: javascript, function, html, onload, getelementbyid

I have this code, and body

```
<body onload="mail_receive()">
```

won't execute it.

```
function mail_receive() {
    document.getElementById("w")="mail receive";
}
```

It won't show in

```
<div id="w"></div>
```

Comment: -1 (No debugging done) Please read the error messages. That will result in a *syntax error* that reads "invalid assignment left-hand side" or similar. If these messages are confusing 1) try google and 2) make sure to include them (the error messages/error indicators) in future posts. This post amounts to "it doesn't work".

Comment: I agree with pst.  It's amazing to me how many people post there problems here in SO and have not looked in the error console.  That's the very FIRST thing one should do when the code isn't working.  It will tell you if you have execution errors and where they are.

Comment: Yeah, but I did not know what that error meant. Sorry for not stating it.

Comment: Yeah, now it's not putting an error.

Answer (score 6):

You can't assign a string value to a DOM element and expect it to work. (In fact you probably can't use the result of a function call as an lvalue in Javascript to begin with.)

Try

```
document.getElementById('w').innerHTML = 'Mail received';
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't know what you mean. I tried it with single quotes if that's what you meant, but it did not work.

Comment: Ha ha, oh sorry, I didn't realize that that had no .innerHTML. In my real one, it has .innerHTML="mail receive"; and it doesn't work.

Comment: Works for me in: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/263227/so-7814863-why-wont-my-function-execute.html – not sure where else the problem could be.

Comment: That's exactly what I have, except it has some other things on it. Just some text, and an input box.

Comment: @njaohnt Can you upload a failing example somewhere?

Comment: This is the source: 
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><script type="text/javascript">
function aaa()
{
document.getElementById('w').innerHTML='Sending email...Don't close this window';}
</script>
</head><body onload="aaa()">Please check your email to finish your account. <form method='get' action='makeaccountt.php'>Type your confirmation code in here:<input type='text' name='con'><br><div id='w'></div></body></html>

Comment: @njaohnt …You have an unescaped apostrophe (i.e. single quote) in the single-quoted string you're passing to `innerHTML` in the word "Don't". This very clearly writes a SyntaxError to the Javascript error console. Doublequoting the string makes it work.

Comment: Okay, I fixed that, but it still doesn't appear. It says "aaa is not defined" in the JS console.

Comment: @njaohnt Are you sure you didn't rename the function inside `script` to `mail_receive` while you were fixing this?